# Intermittent network issues with SafetyNet attest API

Tags: android, safetynet

Experts,

we are having intermittent connection failures with the SafetyNet client on Android. We are using com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet version 11.8.0 but have also seen the issue with version 16.

The issue occurs when the device is connected to a WiFi network without internet connection and then switched to a WiFi network with internet connectivity. In this case the attest method sometimes continues to fail with a status code of 7 (Network Error). Several retries will not solve the issue.

We confirmed that we are not hitting the 'Per-minute, per-user' API quota, which returns a different status code.

Any ideas? Thanks!

```
SafetyNet.getClient(context).attest(nonceBytes, googleApiKey)
    .addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(SafetyNetApi.AttestationResponse response) {
                    // do something here

                }
            })
    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception ex) {
            // An error occurred while communicating with the service.
            if (ex instanceof ApiException) {
                // An error with the Google Play services API contains some additional details.
                ApiException apiException = (ApiException) ex;
                // here we get apiException.getStatusCode() of 7;                          
            } else {
                // other type of exception
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem...